# Finding Minimal lexicographical Array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I tried solving this interview question. My code runs for  test cases  but  fails for all the  real  input test cases. I tried hard to find the mistake but unable to do so. Please find my code below the question

> Bob loves sorting very much. He is always thinking of new ways to sort an array.His friend Ram gives him a challenging task. He gives Bob an array and an integer K. The challenge is to produce the lexicographical minimal array after at most K-swaps. Only consecutive pairs of elements can be swapped. Help Bob in returning the lexicographical minimal array possible after at most K-swaps.
>
> Input: The first line contains an integer `T` i.e. the number of Test cases. `T` test cases follow. Each test case has 2 lines. The first line contains `N(number of elements in array)` and `K(number of swaps)`. The second line contains `n` integers of the array.
>
> Output: Print the lexicographical minimal array.
>
> Constraints:
>
> ```
> 1 <= T <= l0 
>
> 1 <= N,K <= 1000 
>
> 1 <= A[i] <= 1000000
> ```
>
> Sample Input (Plaintext Link)
>
> ```
> 2 
>
> 3 2 
>
> 5 3 1 
>
> 5 3 
>
> 8 9 11 2 1
> ```
>
> Sample Output (Plaintext Link)
>
> ```
> 1 5 3 
>
> 2 8 9 11 1
> ```
>
> Explanation
>
> After swap 1:
>
> ```
> 5 1 3
> ```
>
> After swap 2:
>
> ```
> 1 5 3
> ```

`{1,5,3}` is lexicographically minimal than `{5,1,3}`

Example 2:

> Swap 1: `8 9 2 11 1`
>
> Swap 2: `8 2 9 11 1`
>
> Swap 3: `2 8 9 11 1`

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  void trySwap(int a[], int start, int end, int *rem)
  {
//cout << start << "  " << end << "  " << *rem << endl;
  while (*rem != 0 && end > start)
  {
    if (a[end - 1] > a[end])
    {
        swap(a[end - 1], a[end]);
        (*rem)--;
        end--;
    }
    else end--;
}
}

void getMinimalLexicographicArray(int a[], int size, int k)
{
int start , rem = k, window = k;

for (start = 0; start < size; start++)
{
    window = rem;
    if (rem == 0)
        return;
    else
    {
        //cout << start << " " << rem << endl;
        int end = start + window;
        if (end >= size)
        {
            end = size - 1;
        }
        trySwap(a, start, end, &rem);
    }
}
}

int main()
{
int T, N, K;
int a[1000];
int i, j;

cin >> T;
for (i = 0; i < T; i++)
{
    cin >> N;
    cin >> K;

    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        cin >> a[j];
    }

    getMinimalLexicographicArray(a, N, K);

    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        cout << a[j] << " ";
    cout << endl;

}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Could you link the source of the question so that we can verify that it's not from a running contest?

Comment: http://www.careercup.com/page?pid=directi-interview-questions

Comment: Here's the original: http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/swap-it-2/ . It's a practice problem.

Comment: That is an exam question in thoughtworks hiring process.

Answer (score 1):

Python solution can be easily translated to C++:

```
def findMinArray(arr, k):
  i = 0
  n = len(arr)

  while k > 0 and i < n:
    min_idx = i

    hi = min(n, i + k + 1)

    for j in range(i, hi):
      if arr[j] < arr[min_idx]:
        min_idx = j

    for j in range(min_idx, i, -1):
      arr[j - 1], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[j - 1]

    k -= min_idx - i
    i += 1

  return arr
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two failed test cases.

```
2

2 2
2 1

5 3
3 2 1 5 4
```

In the first, your code makes no swaps, because K >= N. In the second, your code swaps 5 and 4 when it should spend its third swap on 3 and 2.

EDIT: the new version is still too greedy. The correct output for

```
1

10 10
5 4 3 2 1 10 9 8 7 6
```

is

```
1 2 3 4 5 10 9 8 7 6
```

.

Comment: @user2221214 Still buggy.

Comment: Only consecutive pairs of elements can be swapped. The expected answer must be 1 5 4 3 2 10 9 8 7 6